# Mongoexport "ERROR PARSING URI" error - MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport, mongodb-tools

Facing below error while executing mongoexport command.Connection string below.

MongoDB shell version v4.2.0 
OS - Mac OS Catalina

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb+srv://m001-student:m001-****@sandbox.*****.mongodb.net/sample_supplies" --collection=sales --out=sales.json
```

Error:

```
2021-01-14T20:27:59.584+0000    error parsing command line options: error parsing uri: lookup _mongodb._tcp.sandbox.*****.mongodb.net on 192.#.#.#:#:# no such host <br/>


2021-01-14T20:27:59.585+0000    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

I have provided ***ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE*** IP details in network access tab too. In that case, there should not be any issues while connecting. I have installed home-brew in my MacOS and installed mongodb database tools, since my terminal didn't recognise mongoexport command initially.  Please let me know if I'm missing any detail in connection string.

Comment: in my case, I have mistyped a single letter in the uri, check that your uri is correct

Comment: thammada.ts ...  I have just copied the contents from mongo university site and executed the connection string. The double quotes used in the site seems to cause the issue. Guess the unicode stuff issues here... Now its resolved.

Answer (score 9):

delete "+srv" from uri...

Comment: So simple + impossible to find in the docs- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a backup from a remote database and restore it on your local machine.

1. Get your local machine IP by opening the terminal and  running this command `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`
2. Add your machine IP address in the mongo atlas and provide access for this IP to limited hours only. In-network access tab.
3. Run this command `mongodump --uri 'PUT_DB_HERE_URI' --out $(pwd)` which takes a backup from your remote db you will find collection files with extension `.bson`.
4. To restore this data in your local database run this command `mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 -d database_name ./exported_folder_which_contains_.bson files/` .
   As a reference, you can find the details [here](https://tech-hour.com/mongodb-backup)